# Error renaming Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

When trying to execute:

```
db.site-09-15-17-19.renameCollection('site-09-18-17')
```

I get:

```
E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I am not sure what I did wrong here..  I can use the site-09-15-17-19 collection just fine, just can't rename it.

Comment: Have you tried with " instead of ' ?

Comment: Yes, both.  No luck so far.

Comment: and db.site-09-15-17-19.find() returns results as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use runCommand to rename collection. Before you run the command change to admin db

```
use admin
db.runCommand({renameCollection:"testdb.site-09-15-17-19",to:"testdb.site-09-18-17"})
```